# iPhone top status bar gets stuck on right hand side after page change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 2 pages.

Page A: (Portrait mode)
Page B: (Landscape mode)

Go from Page A --> B, then back to Page A. The status bar is stuck on the right hand side (despite the fact that the phone is back in portrait mode. Normally it eventually redraws itself in the correct position, but this can take a few seconds, which is unacceptable. The two pages are connected via Modal segues in storyboards and I haven't implemented anything whacky...

Here is the shouldRotate method in Page A. Think I left this standard.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with screenshots?

Comment: It's just sitting on the right hand side all the way down..... When it should have reverted to the top...

Comment: Things were changed in iOS 6. Perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6/12522119#12522119