# How to set the starting orientation to landscape?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

Hi I was checking the orientations changes of iOS6 and I made everything work fine except one thing. There is no way to start the app on landscape.

How can I do to start the app on landscape? I found this [How to force a UIViewController to Portrait orientation in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6) but that's not working, the app ALWAYS start in portrait and I needed to start it on landscape...

When I go to an other view and then go back to the "initial view" it is on landscape! But when the app starts it's on portrait...

Thank you!!

----------------------------- UPDATE -------------------------------

This is how I'm loading from the app delegate the main view:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
myViewController = [[myViewController alloc] init];

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController] ;

[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

----------------------------- UPDATE 2------------------------------
I made it work, I changed the previous code for:

```
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init] ;
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[navController presentViewController:myViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

I hope this is useful for someone else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I made it work:

```
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init] ;
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[navController presentViewController:myViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

I hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];
```

This is working for me in both iOS 6 and iOS 5

I have another problem on trying to rotate the screen than I realize I was making the mistake of try to load the new screen with:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

instead of:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

the second one works but the first one wasn't doing what I expected.

Comment: thanks for the tips but I'm not using any of this lines in my app... this is driving me crazy...

Comment: Try the first code line. In my case I use the `setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` on my app because I have to force the view to stay on Portrait when a video(that play on full screen and can be rotated) finishes on Landscape mode.

Comment: no useful for me... It's driving me crazy, because my app loads a view, that view is not in landscape (i need it to be landscape) after loading immediately calls an other view, when I go back the first view it's in landscape, but it doesn't starts on landscape... really odd... I'm out of ideas..

Comment: the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation it's not called on load... but when I come back to the view it is called...

Comment: Can you tell me how are you calling the first view in both cases?

Comment: from my app delegate:self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController] ; [self.window setRootViewController:navController];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Answer (score -1):

I've been wrestling with this too - this is how I've fixed it:

In viewDidLoad:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;

if (frame.size.height > frame.size.width) {
    //hack to force landscape
    CGFloat holdHeight = frame.size.height;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.width;
    frame.size.width = holdHeight;
    self.view.bounds = frame;
}
```

But I'd prefer a better way.