# iOS6 autorotation confusion and support for iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

Since iOS6, I realize that the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method has been deprecated.  Most of my app I would like the user to be able to rotate, which does work in iOS6 and 5 currently. But, I have a modal view that I ONLY want to be `portrait`, so I have added the following without it actually working (tested in simulator and device):

```
// Tell the system what we support
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

// Tell the system It should autorotate
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

// Tell the system which initial orientation we want to have
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

**Why isn't this code preventing my modal from rotating?
How can I still support the iOS5 method as well as the iOS6 methods without crashing for users on iOS5?**

Comment: modals are presented by a parent. what happens if you conditionally stop  the parent from rotating

Comment: No, putting those in the parent `viewController` didn't stop the rotation.

Comment: If you implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` it won't cause it to crash on iOS 5. Just implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` as well as the iOS 6 methods.

Comment: I was meaning, since I support iOS5, will the iOS6 methods cause a crash for iOS5 users.

Comment: @Nic Hubbard: The iOS6 methods will never be called when running on an iOS 5 device and the iOS 5 methods will never be called when running on an iOS 6 device. You may safely have both the iOS 5 and iOS 6 methods in the same app with no issues.

Comment: @RoboticCat Ok good. I guess I am just used to having to take that into account when setting properties that are new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to embed the presented vc in a navigation controller where you can set the preferred orientation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522119

Answer (score 0):

You missed to but this line inside your `-(void)viewDidLoad` method

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"UIApplicationSupportedInterfaceOrientationsIsEnabled"];
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: I don't see any evidence that this line has any effect.