# shouldAutoRotate Method Not Called in iOS6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, rotation, ios6

I have a `UIViewController` detail view which is pushed from a `UITableView` in a `UINavigationController`. In the `UIViewController` I add a number of subviews (e.g a `UITextView`, `UIImageView`).

In `iOS5` I used this code to stop autorotation if my picture view was enlarged :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
if (scrollView.isZoomed) {
    return NO;
}
else {
    return YES;
}
```

}

I am trying to achieve the same thing under `iOS6` using :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return FALSE;
}
```

However this method is never called and the app continues rotating.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Are you using a navigtion controller?

Comment: Yes that's right - sorry meant to mention that.

Comment: UINavigationControllers don't check with their children for rotation decisions. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Navigation Controller managing these views, the *shouldAutorotate* method won't be called. You would have to subclass **UINavigationController** and override methods *shouldAutorotate* and *supportedIntervalOrientations*.

From the docs:

> Now, iOS containers (such as UINavigationController) do not consult their children to determine whether they should autorotate

Edit-----

As mentioned below by Lomax, subclassing UINavigationController is discouraged by Apple. You should try a category instead ([this SO question explains it well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6)):

```
@implementation UINavigationController 
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    // your code
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    (...)
}

@end
```

Comment: From UINavigationController documentation: This class is not intended for subclassing --> if you subclass your app will probably be rejected.

Comment: You are right, it is better to use categories. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks - how do I use a category - is it just a custom class ?

Comment: Check the SO link in the answer. Also, this is a good tutorial on categories: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/objective-c-categories/

Comment: UINavigation Documentation as of iOS 6..."This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later."  So subclassing will not get your app rejected.  [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Categories are used in objective c for adding new methods to existing classes. Using category for method overriding is bad practice. SUBCALSS UINavigationController in iOS >= 6.0.