# Rotate keyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the line to change my view orientation, it works.

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
```

However, my keyboard still remain the same way it does, not following my view rotation. My question is, how do I change my keyboard orientation together, like after the line? My interface is only support Portrait, I just want to do it programmatically. Thanks.

P/S: Deployment target 6.1

Comment: Have you looked [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15443637/1008736)?

Comment: Thanks @jjv360, but I need to rotate the view and keyboard only, the solution there seems to do it all. For example, I need my tab bar controller stay Portrait, even my view is on Landscape mode.