# Interface Orientation for iOS 6 is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, orientation

I have a app which i want to display in portrait mode. But I only want to show one view in both modes.

I have do this for iOS5 . But in iOS6,i can't able to do this.

I also tried many codes to solved it.

**i use navigation in my app & rotate only one view in both mode is not possible in ios6. Either you fixed your rotation for a view or rotate whole app. Am i right?**

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: What is the Deployment Target? Did you implement any of the new iOS 6 rotation methods?

Comment: my deployment target is 5.1 & yes i try with shouldAutorotate & supportedInterfaceOrientation method .

Comment: r u using UINavigation controller???

Comment: yes, i am using navigation controller & i also taken Tab Bar in all xib

Comment: @Prince, yes, i am using navigation controller & i also taken Tab Bar in all xib

Comment: @Prince, can you post some code??

Comment: @user1673099 did my effort help you?

Comment: @MilKyWaY, thanks for reply but sorry to say that still i am not able to solve the problem.

Comment: @MilKyWaY, i use navigation in my app & rotate only one view in both mode is not possible in ios6. Either you fixed your rotation for a view or rotate whole app.  Am i right???

Answer (score 1):

in ios6 have you trying with this in plist like bellow image:-

[image]

and you can also set at xcode->projectname->summary:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply..but i also want to show one view in landscape mode so i select all orientation in summary

Comment: yes you can put autoration for only one view in Landscap and you can also impliment Catagory of NavigationController to suport actuly and currect oriation

Comment: can you post some code How to do that? I want to show only one view in both mode & others are in only portrait mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6

Comment: i try code But when i rotate in landscape then all views are display landscape. I just enable both mode for only one view.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's iOS 6 SDK Release Notes:

> Autorotation is changing in iOS 6. In iOS 6, the
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method of UIViewController is
>   deprecated. In its place, you should use the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: and shouldAutorotate methods.
>
> ```
> More responsibility is moving to the app and the app delegate. Now, iOS containers (such as UINavigationController) do not consult
> ```
>
> their children to determine whether they should autorotate. By
>   default, an app and a view controller’s supported interface
>   orientations are set to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad
>   idiom and UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone
>   idiom.
>
> ```
> A view controller’s supported interface orientations can change over time—even an app’s supported interface orientations can change
> ```
>
> over time. The system asks the top-most full-screen view controller
>   (typically the root view controller) for its supported interface
>   orientations whenever the device rotates or whenever a view controller
>   is presented with the full-screen modal presentation style. Moreover,
>   the supported orientations are retrieved only if this view controller
>   returns YES from its shouldAutorotate method. The system intersects
>   the view controller’s supported orientations with the app’s supported
>   orientations (as determined by the Info.plist file or the app
>   delegate’s application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:
>   method) to determine whether to rotate.
>
> ```
> The system determines whether an orientation is supported by intersecting the value returned by the app’s
> ```
>
> supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: method with the value
>   returned by the supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most
>   full-screen controller. The setStatusBarOrientation:animated: method
>   is not deprecated outright. It now works only if the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most full-screen view
>   controller returns 0. This makes the caller responsible for ensuring
>   that the status bar orientation is consistent.
>
> ```
> For compatibility, view controllers that still implement the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method do not get the new
> ```
>
> autorotation behaviors. (In other words, they do not fall back to
>   using the app, app delegate, or Info.plist file to determine the
>   supported orientations.) Instead, the
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method is used to synthesize
>   the information that would be returned by the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientations method.
>
> If you want your whole app to rotate then you should set your
>   Info.plist to support all orientations. Now if you want a specific
>   view to be portrait only you will have to do some sort of subclass and
>   override the autorotation methods to return portrait only.

See this example [How to force a UIViewController to Portrait orientation in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6/12522119#12522119)

**EDIT:**

Solutions:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
```

Comment: it can't be solved through a few lines of code, you can see the solution in the link I referred at the bottom, did't you check this?

Comment: can i post my code?? I refer your link but it did not help me

Comment: If you want all of our navigation controllers to respect the top view controller you can use a category so you don't have to go through and change a bunch of class names...make sense?

Comment: how can i make subclass of NavigationController class

Comment: Dont you know categorising?

Comment: see http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/objective-c-categories/ and do this in case of your navigation controller and add the code I had shown, then it will work.thats all I can help