# Can you make an iOS app landscape only?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a cool idea for an iOS application but I want to make it landscape only to create the best experience for it.

Is this possible and not against any apple guidelines?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of understanding and knowledge about iOS applications and iOS SDK.

Comment: Yes, can be done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409310/force-landscape-for-one-view-controller-ios

Comment: I'm voting down because of an obvious lack of research on either SO, Google or the Apple Documentation.
Andy please, make sure to look around before asking :)

Answer (score 4):

In your General settings in Xcode, choose Landscape Left and Landscape Right to make your app landscape only.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Yeah it is possible..you can do that.In general settings you can select that(Landscape left + Landscape right). There are many apps which run only in landscape. For example you take games like PvZ(PlantVSzombies).Its not against apple guidelines.
Here is the link of the app, you can check that

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/plants-vs.-zombies-2/id597986893?mt=8

and you must read apple guidelines :-

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: Its good to add comment for downvote. please downvoter give your valuable feedback.