# Keep all views portrait except one

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

Right I have done a lot of research on this and have hit a block.

I am developing an app which has multiple view controllers. I have the 'homepage', if you will, which all the others views can be access from (this ViewController.m). I also then have a UINavigationController.m attached to the ViewController.m to allow a full navigation bar etc.

My problem is that I am wanting all views to be shown in portrait EXCEPT one view, which I only want in landscape. In my app options, I have set it to enable all orientations and then I was reading that you should override the main orientation in your root view controller (which I assume is the navigation controller?), so I add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

This overrides everything and only portrait works. I have then tried adding:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

To the view that I want to have in landscape only but it fails to work in the simulator.

Can anyone provide me with a solution? :/

(I would like iOS5 and iOS6 support if possible)

[EDIT]

I should add, I haven't edited AppDelegate in any way.

Comment: for that one view you need portrait landscape both orientation support?

Comment: No I just need landscape for that one view. I want to force the portrait view on everything else and then force landscape on this one view. I was looking https://devforums.apple.com/message/744384#744384 at this, but I'm unsure as to where I'm going wrong

Comment: Have to checked, last two methods supportedInterfaceOrientations & supportedInterfaceOrientations are placed in the view controller which u need only landscape orientation?

Comment: try this link it might be a helpful one  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633213/force-portrait-orientation-while-pushing-from-landscape-view-controller

Comment: @Ganapathy - those methods have been added to the view controller that I want in landscape.