# iPhone lock portrait orientation

Tags: ios, orientation

I realize there are a few threads regarding this issue. However, I am new to this, and some of the solutions I found did not work for me.

I have an iPhone app that should support all orientations except in one view. This view I would like to lock in portrait only. I tried this code, but it still goes to landscape mode when I flip the phone... what am I doing wrong?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` has been [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) in iOS 6.0.

You should now override the `supportedInterfaceOrientation` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` classes.

Like so:

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code above, but the view still goes to landscape mode when I flip the phone... is there anything else I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: Did you remove the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` class from your code?

Comment: I found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6/12522119#12522119

Comment: +1 - Funny, I was just reading through this post when you added your comment. It's meant to be!

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that if you're using a UINavigationController, it will not normally forward the supportedInterfaceOrientations call to the top view controller.  Subclass UINavigationController and add:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

seems to be the cleanest answer.  There are other approaches that involve putting the code in your app delegate, using categories to add the code to UINavigationController, etc., but this seems the cleanest solution to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the code, but I got an error message, stating "Property topViewController not found..."

Comment: You need to put this code into a UINavigationController subclass and then make sure that your storyboard references the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You must lock the controller in your RootViewController(eg.UITabbarController or UINavigationController) . When your device rotate,**First** It will call AppDelegate's rotateMethod(eg.- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate , - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations).**Then** It call RootViewController's RotateMehod.

**1.If your RootViewController is UITabbarController, add code like following code in your UITabbarController**(NotRotateController is the controller your do not want go to landscape mode )

```
#import "NotRotateController.h"
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    UINavigationController * baseNavCtr = self.viewControllers[self.selectedIndex];
    if ([baseNavCtr.topViewController isKindOfClass:[NotRotateController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
}
```

**2.If your RootViewController is UINavigationContoller**

```
#import "NotRotateController.h"

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.topViewController isKindOfClass:[NotRotateController class]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

3.**Summarize**, judge your the Controller in RootViewController'     `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` method ,return the orientation your want to surport

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1- Add these 2 functions to App Delegate. Read the comments for  more information

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    // 1.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        if let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController) {

            if (rootViewController.responds(to: Selector(("canRotate")))) {
                // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
                return .allButUpsideDown
            }

            // *** THIS WILL GET CALLED WHEN THE VC CALLS THIS SELECTOR ***
            if (rootViewController.responds(to: Selector(("cantRotate")))) {
                // Unlock portrait only view orientation for this view controller
                return .portrait
            }
        }

        // Allow all orientations but upside down
        return .allButUpsideDown
    }

    // 2.
    private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
        if (rootViewController == nil) { return nil }
        if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self)) {
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
        } else if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self)) {
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
        } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
        }
        return rootViewController
    }
}
```

2- Add this to the vc you want to be Portrait only:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Portrait Only. The first function above inside App Delegate responds to this
    @objc func cantRotate() {}
}
```