# iPhone Interface orientation is incorrect

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uideviceorientation

On iPhone - my first `ViewController` supports all interface orientations. Initial behavior though, is when I launch the app the main `ViewController` should always be in portrait.

In order to overcome situations where the phone was in landscape while the app was launched, I created a dummy `ViewController` which only supported portrait orientation, launched the app from it and immediately pushed the main `ViewController`. Indeed the main `ViewController` was in portrait orientation, but when performing:

`self.interfaceOrientation`

The result was landscape orientation (like the phone's orientation).
I would expect it to return portrait, and this is causing problems.
How can I get the true orientation of the `ViewController` and not the device in this case?

Comment: Have you tried `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` ?

Comment: Yes, and unfortunatlly didn't help and therefor resorted to the hack of the dummy view controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to override your UINavController to set the orientation in portrait when you want. It's that Vihba means.

The problem is that navController keeps orientation of last view...

Answer (score -1):

**Use this code *****

Also you can refer following link:
[How to force a UIViewController to Portrait orientation in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6)

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate

{

return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{

return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];

}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

{

    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];

}
```