# TabBarController rotation problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

All week I have been searching SO for a solution to my unique problem, but nothing has worked for me yet. I have a TabBarController that has 6 tabs. iOS automatically creates the "More" tab, which contains the view controller,"Dashboard", that I am having difficulty with. The "Dashboard" view controller is acting as a page controller that has 3 pages.

When I press the "Dashboard" item, I want the screen orientation to change from Portrait to Landscape. I've learned through countless other SO posts that rotation is controlled from the parent TabBarController. I have also learned that the "More" tab is actually a navigation controller, which adds some more complication to the mix.

To reiterate and be direct, when I press the "Dashboard" tab in the TabBarController's "More" tab, I want the screen to change its orientation from Portrait to Landscape.

And YES, I have already tried this: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]forKey:@"orientation"];` and it didn't work.

I've also tried overriding every function in the TabBarController and MoreNavigationController that has to do with rotation and orientation, as well as in the child views. I will post my TabBarController below. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

**TabBarViewController.h:**

```
@interface TabBarViewController : UITabBarController<UINavigationControllerDelegate>{}
@end
```

**TabBarViewController.m:**

```
@implementation TabBarViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[Dashboard class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)tabBarControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
{
    if([tabBarController.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[Dashboard class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    NSLog(@"tabBarController didSelectViewController = %lu", (unsigned long)tabBarController.selectedIndex);

}

- (NSUInteger)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
{
    if([navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[Dashboard class]]
       || [navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController1 class]]
       || [navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]
       || [navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController3 class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)navigationControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
{
    NSLog(@"navigationControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation");
    if([navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[Dashboard class]]
       || [navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController1 class]]
       || [navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]
       || [navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController3 class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[Dashboard class]])
    {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]forKey:@"orientation"];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: From my own research and understanding of what I have read, TabBarControllers can't rotate. So what I did instead was have a Portrait viewController for the "Dashboard" that listened for changes in orientation. When the orientation changes to landscape, I modally present my page view controller

Comment: I guess you could try to have the TabBarViewController modally present the pageViewController when "Dashboard" is selected, instead of trying to rotate the device......

Comment: `TabBarViewController`, for one reason or another, needs a trigger to rotate, but it can be done. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32390717/218152 shows how to achieve orientation changes on `TabBarViewController` without being modal.

Answer (score 0):

## Changing the orientation of a UITabBarController

While there are dozens of *maybe* and *try this* for this problem, the main issue reside in the careful design of each `UINavigationController`, a proper response to `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in the `UITabBarController`, and some code to enforce the desired orientation.

In all likelihood, this may just be an iOS bug, since once rotated, the `UINavBarController` and all embedded `UINavigationController` behave correctly.

The following statement is **not true**. Tab bar controllers **do rotate**.

> TabBarControllers can't rotate

---

**Setup orientation for each `UINavigationController`**

Landscape example:

```
class HorizontalNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscape
    }
}
```

Portrait example:

```
class VerticalNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

**Defer `TabBarController` orientation to selected view controller**

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if let selectedViewController = selectedViewController {
            return selectedViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations
        }
        return .allButUpsideDown
    }
}
```

**Enforce the interface orientation change**

This is the contentious aspect of `UITabBarController`. Somehow, the orientation change does not happen like it would in a `UINavigationController`, and needs a nudge.

To do so with the fewest amount of code, use an Object and subclass it into a `TabBarControllerDelegate`. You can do [most of the work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175661/set-uitabbarcontroller-created-in-interface-builder-as-delegate/32390374#32390374) in Interface Builder.

```
class TabBarControllerDelegate: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let orientedViewController = UIViewController()

        tabBarController.present(orientedViewController, animated: false) { () -> Void in
            tabBarController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Storyboard Structure**

Using a `Storyboard` helps visualize the structure of the application as well as the relationship between all classes.

[image: Storyboard]

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32255151) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-32255151).