# PageTabBarController as a custom class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cosmicmind

How to set custom class for a view controller from storyboard to point to  **PageTabBarController**?

[image]

Currently I am getting

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D0067EFA-F147-4500-9528-835B359CE993/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9AB84E67-96A5-4CC0-AA53-3F292511260E/PageTabBarController.app> (loaded)' with name 'TXs-jd-44x-view-mDN-5j-iHs''
```

And here is the original code I am editing https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Material/Programmatic/PageTabBarController

Comment: This seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5337337/218152

Comment: thanks @SwiftArchitect, actually I want to understand how can I use PageTabBarController through storyboard, or how can I mix things between stroyboard and code

Comment: You can find a very extensive answer with a sample project on this StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32390717/218152

Comment: @AnasSalman I am going to experiment a bit with making this happen. Currently setting the `rootViewController` is a challenge. If you don't hear from me within a couple days, please ping me, or feel free to make a github issue that links to this.