# Prevent rotation of ViewControllers in navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

My navigation stack looks like this:

```
[UINavigationController] ---> [ViewController1] ---> [ViewController2] ...
```

I want to lock `ViewController1` in portrait orientation but `ViewController2` can rotate freely.
 I tried to put these line of codes in various places but they don't work.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

I also tried to sub-classing `UINavigationController` as well (accepted answer in few other questions with similiar issue) but nothing works.
I'm also having a left sidebar controller using `MMDrawerViewController`.

The problem is `ViewController1` can still rotate to other orientations, after many attempts.
Anybody know how to fix this ? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: similar to what you wants. can modify in logic in answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116967/youtube-video-directly-not-playing-to-landscape-mode-ios-7/25119235#25119235

Comment: Where exactly are you facing problems? Please be a little more elaborate.

Comment: `n00bProgrammer` I've editted my question.


`MohitPopat` ok, I'm going to try it now, but it seems to be not a good solution.

Comment: @PhamHoan yes you are right. i also write there not a great solution but helpful solution

Comment: Subclassing should work and inside the `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` you can check the class of `self.topViewController` to return the correct mask, or call ` [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];` from the navigationController.

Comment: @Jkmn not in my case, I don't know what's wrong. I even made a `UINavigationController` category and `import` it everywhere. Does nothing.
I used this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6