# Create UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification event manually

Tags: ios, events, rotation

Can we create UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification event manually?

In AppDelegate.swif
I have

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
```

this method will return a result depends on user setting.

It work well but user need change setting during app running.

But the setting will be effective after user rotate the device, what I want is let it effective immediately

Answer (score 0):

Use `NotificationCenter` -

```
setupRotationListener()

/// Setup rotation listener
    func setupRotationListener() -> Void {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)

    }

    /// Remove rotationListener
    func removeRotationlistener() -> Void {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)

    }

    /// Rotate camera
    func rotated() {
        //do your task 
 if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
    }
```

Comment: I want fake an event, not observer the event.

Answer (score 0):

[I found a solution from stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14445888/2293677)

His solution is really solve my problem:

**In iOS <= 4 and iOS >= 6:**

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[vc release];
```

**In iOS 5:**

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView *view = [window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[view removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:view];
```